# Building an eGPU from scratch for a MacBook Air

Tags: graphics-card, macbook, computer-building

So I purchased a MacBook Air Early 2014 model last year, and have realised that my current setup is absolutely useless for playing graphically intensive games if I expect to get over 27fps on low. I run my games on Windows and Mac OS X, and  I have decided that I want to go with an eGPU. The thing is, I have absolutely no hardware experience at all, and have a few things that I want to achieve.

First of all, I've seen things like the "Bizon Box" which allows me to hook everything up into one singular box and use it from there, except I feel that it is extremely overpriced and I could make one much cheaper.

I recently asked a friend, who told me that my CPU and RAM would bottleneck with what I want to do aswell. I have 4GB of RAM and an Intel i5 4260U CPU which can turbo boost to around 2.3GHz. I don't understand in what way my computer could "bottleneck", but if this is going to be an issue, I might as well just skip it and build a custom computer from scratch.

Lastly, I have an external HDMI monitor which I want to use for gaming. I know that I can hook the eGPU into my Thunderbolt 2 port, but then I have nothing for the HDMI to go into, so can I then connect that straight to the GPU?

I need to know if this is going to be a good decision, or just build a computer from scratch for probably $100 or so dollars more. I'm trying to do this on the cheap end, I don't want to go over $450AUD for an eGPU when I can build a gaming computer (albeit cheap) for the same price if not $100 more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaming on a laptop is rarely a good idea. Either graphics performance is lacking or you pay a premium. If you start with a regular laptop and you want to increase graphics performance then you only have a few options:

1. A new laptop. (Mentioned for completeness sake).
2. An expensive MXM board on a laptop for was already prepared for that.
3. An external GPU, which seems to be the road you already decided upon.

For external GPU's we currently have three viable options:

1. Wire something from a intenral mini PCI-e slot.
2. Wire something from an expresscard slot.
3. Use Thunderbolt.

All three expose PCI-e lane(s). Eiter directly, or multiplexed.

Given that you have a laptop which has a Thunderbolt 2 port and an OS which is probably the best one to use Thunderbolt devices this seems the way to go.

> Lastly, I have an external HDMI monitor which I want to use for gaming.
>   I know that I can hook the eGPU into my Thunderbolt 2 port, but then I 
>   have nothing for the HDMI to go into, so can I then connect that straight
>   to the GPU?

For best performance you probably want an external graphics card and connect your monitor directly to that cards out. So you get:

```
         Thunderbolt cable           (DP or DVI or HDMI)
Laptop ======================= eGPU ------------------------Monitor
```

> I'm trying to do this on the cheap end, I don't want to go over $450AUD
>   for an eGPU when I can build a gaming computer (albeit cheap) for the
>   same price if not $100 more.

Here you have a problem. Thunderbolt-1 and Thuderbolt-2 are great technical products. Far superior to USB-3. But they never were mass produced and they are priced as most niche products are.

Hopefully this will change now that Thunderbolt-3 (with USB-C connector) is getting common, but that will not help your laptop. As I see it you only have two choices:

1. Spent more money than you want to keep one laptop and add gaming performance.
2. Or build a cheap desktop and maintain two system. Which probably is not a big problem if all you do is use the desktop for gaming, but one system with all documents in the same place is more userfriendly.

Comment: Thankyou for the insightful answer. I ended up deciding I might as well just build one from scratch. It would be nice to have a desktop PC alongside my portable laptop.